# Cloudmin GPL Xen PV with Nat Port Forwarding

Tags: iptables, nat, port-forwarding

I'm running Cloudmin GPL on CentOS 5 64bit and am trying to allow my Xen PV guest to access the internet via a NAT/port forwarding setup.. I've done the following:

(on dom0)

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 8001 -j DNAT --to 192.168.3.2:22
```

info from http://jonmccune.wordpress.com/2008/08/25/iptables-nat-in-xen/

```
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1C:C0:F2:23:1A  
          inet addr:x.x.x.35  Bcast:199.x.x.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:346089 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:180430 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:484168952 (461.7 MiB)  TX bytes:15039620 (14.3 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:4574 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4574 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2152282 (2.0 MiB)  TX bytes:2152282 (2.0 MiB)

peth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:350814 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:181306 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:491256661 (468.4 MiB)  TX bytes:14977668 (14.2 MiB)
          Interrupt:22 Memory:d0700000-d0720000 

vif0.0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:180439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:346090 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:15040646 (14.3 MiB)  TX bytes:484169018 (461.7 MiB)

vif7.0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1620 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:384 (384.0 b)  TX bytes:109172 (106.6 KiB)

xenbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8631 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:405819 (396.3 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

Added ip "192.168.3.2" to the guest and started the guest but theres no internet connectivity or port forwarding to -> guest or from guest.

I can't find any option in cloudmin gpl to provide nat port forwarding?